# Swift how to detect if keyboard is fully visible or fully hidden only (and not partially visible)

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter, uikeyboard

This question is related to the following questions: [Detect when keyboard is fully visible and prevent keyboard appearance handling code from adding extra offset for hidden element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65749069/detect-when-keyboard-is-fully-visible-and-prevent-keyboard-appearance-handling-c?noredirect=1#comment116251829_65749069)

I was initially using notifications like `NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardDidShow`, `NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardDidHide` hoping they would be triggered only once, hence enabling me to set a bool that the keyboard is fully displayed or that it is hidden.

But what I have noticed is that all the events: `UIKeyboardWillShow`, `UIKeyboardDidShow`, `UIKeyboardWillHide`, `UIKeyboardDidHide`, `UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame`, `UIKeyboardDidChangeFrame` are designed to trigger multiple times as the keyboard appears or disappears.

There seems to be no way to check if a keyboard is completely visible and not partially visible. All the answers I looked at listened to these notifications and did calculations to avoid the views from being hidden by the keyboard. But I could not find any way to see if a keyboard is fully displayed (or fully hidden)

I even looked into [KeyboardObserver](https://cocoapods.org/pods/KeyboardObserver) which makes it easier to observe keyboard events, But since it's still based on the default notifications, it's KeyboardEventType.didShow and KeyboardEventType.didHide are triggered multiple times as keyboard appears and disappears.

There should be a better way to tell if a keyboard is fully visible or not visible!

Comment: Just an idea, although I've never tried it. `UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame` gives you the frame of the keyboard in screen coordinates. Couldn't you see if this frame fully intersects with the screen's frame? You'd have to use some `CGRect` translations and calculations: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgrect/1456316-contains

Comment: I tried using the end-frame, but its height is variable so I can't really use that either. Is there some other property that gives me the final keyboard height?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of a property to check if the keyboard is available in the screen:

```swift
extension UIApplication {

    var isKeyboardPresented: Bool {
        if let keyboardWindowClass = NSClassFromString("UIRemoteKeyboardWindow"),
            self.windows.contains(where: { $0.isKind(of: keyboardWindowClass) }) {
            return true
        } 
        else {
            return false
        }
    }

}

if UIApplication.shared.isKeyboardPresented {
    print("Keyboard presented") }
else { 
    print("Keyboard is not presented")
}
```

Comment: Nice trick, but this places a dependency on private API and could break at any point in the future.

Comment: which private api is this?

Comment: he's referring to `UIRemoteKeyboardWindow`, which is not publicly accessible.

Comment: This doesn't work on xcode 14+